# Cannot locate broken part on maintenance diagram - YAMAHA 2018 XV250

Tags: motorcycle, carburetor

The following part broke off the carb, and I don't know what it is and cannot locate it on the vehicle diagrams.

[image: This broke]

As you can see, its just to the left of where the throttle cables attach, and just below where the choke is attached.
I checked the [parts diagram](https://www.partzilla.com/catalog/yamaha/motorcycle/2018/xv250-xv250jb/carburetor) for my vehicle, and I don't see anything there.